# Application init method (as advertised in the docs)

Tags: extjs, extjs-mvc, extjs4.1

I am working with ExtJS 4.1 RC3 - following the MVC pattern. Today was the first time I've needed to implement some logic before any controllers get initialized. I remembered [**this**](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Application-method-init) method from Ext.app.Application and decided to put it to use.

It never seems to get fired, I can't find what is supposed to be firing it either.

I found one [small unanswered thread](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?147817-ExtJS-MVC-init-and-launch) about this method not working from Sep 2011. The poster's solution was to refactor his app. Does this work for everyone else or does no one else use this?

I am coding this the same way I would use the launch method. Is that wrong? Here is what the code looks like:

```
// app.js
Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',

    autoCreateViewport: true,

    controllers: ['myController'],

    init: function() {
        console.log('init'); // this never gets called
    },

    launch: function() {
        console.log('launch'); // this works fine
    }

});
```

Comment: I've got a feeling you were upgrading some code from ExtJs 4.07 to ExtJs 4.1. Is that true? Can I ask you couple questions about this?

Comment: @sha very true, I was actually refactoring a non-MVC 4.07 app to MVC 4.1. I had no idea what was involved before I got started... Would be happy to answer Qs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in the framework. I've pushed up a fix that will hopefully make it into the 4.1.1 release.

Comment: In the meantime I am performing the logic I needed in a "Main" controller's init method instead, I might prefer doing it that way in any case.

Answer (score 3):

I'm working in ExtJs 4.0.7 and the init method does not fire (bug)
For better or worse my workaround is to call it myself.

```
launch: function() {
    this.init();
    console.log('launch'); // this works fine
}
```

Now the above init method is reachable:

```
  init: function() {

    console.log('init'); // this gets called
    // For example here's a quick way to stop an Ext Task... 
    this.on({

      stopEvents: function() {
       Ext.TaskManager.stopAll();
      }

    })
  }
},
```